# string manipulation - stringing '&' between a list of args

Tags: python, string

I have a list of args

```
args = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'... ... ... (long list)]
```

I would like make a string called 'clipboard' where:

```
clipboard = 'abc&def&ghi&... ... ... (long list)'
```

**Pointers would be appreciated.**

Comment: Don't forget to read the python docs: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods

Comment: @jdi - Couldn't find .join I knew I had came across it before!

Comment: @jdi To be fair, many people think of this as a list method and wouldn't think to look in the docs for string methods. Also, if you haven't done it before, there is no reason to even think of the word "join" for a google search.

Comment: @katylavallee: Yea I agree that its not immediately apparent to look at string methods vs list methods...but then again, reviewing docs for the basic python object types (str, list, dict) would pretty quickly turn up with this method amongst the reading. I was hoping to reinforce to the OP the benefits of reviewing docs for fundamentals. The first result for a google search of "python list to string" has the `join` example

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`clipboard = '&'.join(args)`